# run next.js example apps with next source code

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web-development-server

I am having a difficult time in trying to run next.js example apps (basic-css) locally while using next.js source code. I have a terminal where next.js repo is run with

```
pnpm dev
```

, and another terminal where i'am running

```
pnpm next-with-deps ./examples/basic-css/
```

but i get the following error

```
- error ./pages/_app.tsx
Error: missing field `enabled` at line 1 column 988
- warn Mismatching @next/swc version, detected: 13.4.13-canary.2 while Next.js is on 13.4.5-canary.2. Please ensure these match
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- error ./pages/_app.tsx
Error: missing field `enabled` at line 1 column 988
```

The node version I am using is 18.17.0 and I am on Ubuntu 20

Anybody has faced this issue ?

I tried to run next.js source code locally to use it to run the example apps. I am expecting the example app to be run.